# Is oral intercourse permitted according to halacha?

Tags: halacha, sexuality

What has the halacha have to say about a husband and wife sharing oral intercourse (in either direction)?

Comment: @DavidPerlman, the policy for this type of question is evolving here: http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/123/how-modest-should-this-site-be/125#comment-206 . You (and everyone else here) are welcome to join the discussion and help us come up with a policy that is best for this community.

Comment: I don't understand why this was closed.  This is an open-shut *halachic* question that isn't explicit or vulgar.  And the statement "questions relating to sexuality are discussed only in private," is patently false, as amply demonstrated in the meta-discussion.  Voting to reopen.

Comment: All these questions are very similar to this one, and have not been closed.  Why has this one remained closed?http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/35983/intercourse-with-a-co-wife-present | http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/34483/are-sex-change-operations-prohibited-for-non-jews | http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/31971/when-is-there-a-heter-to-use-a-condom | http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/30440/aside-from-the-days-set-aside-for-impurity-what-exactly-is-a-man-allowed-to-do

Comment: @Shmuel http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/34217/why-has-judaism-traditionally-discussed-intimacy-only-privately/34247#34247

Comment: @Yishai - I only mentioned asking one's rabbi because this was stated earlier in the thread, as an alternative to asking it here. Somebody who simply wants to know (תורה היא וללמוד אני צריך), but who doesn't have the background that enables them to consult sefarim - how should they go about it?

Comment: @ShimonbM, I'm glad we cleared that up. I misunderstood you. (BTW, the sites I alluded to should fill that need as well).

Comment: Read Shu"t Bnei Banim

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because of the previous reason it was closed. I would appreciate a final decision from the moderators.

Comment: @Yishai (or anybody else who sees this): please consider bringing this up on meta (explaining why you think it should be closed) so the community can weigh in.  This is a community decision, not a moderator one.  (BTW I cast the fifth reopen vote; I didn't use my mod privileges.)

Comment: possible dupe http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/30440/759

Comment: @ray, I am very surprised at the suggestion that people should refrain from [asking their own rabbi](http://yodeya.com/q/9146/) about a question of Halacha. Like with all questions, some rabbis are qualified to answer without consulting others and some aren't. It's up to rabbis to judge when they need to consult a greater rabbi, and it's up to Jews to choose rabbis to ask who can make such judgments appropriately. Mi Yodeya is [quite adamant](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/1734/) that pseudonymous internet users are not part of this chain of authority.

Comment: This is a question that is personal in nature and whose answer depends on the circumstances under which it is being asked. It involves a number of issues for which a general answer in not applicable. **Rabbinical guidance is needed.** For example, a Rabbi may rule that a particular behavior is permissible for a couple that is experiencing marital issues in an effort to save the marriage. That same behavior would be inappropriate for a couple who is not in that situation. To generalize answers of this type is akin to prescribing medication without knowing the symptoms. This forum is wonderful a

Comment: @MonicaCellio [Done](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/2034/discussion-on-specific-question-of-an-adult-nature).

Comment: As worded, this question is not asking for practical advice or a pesak, nor is,it "personal in nature". It asks "what Halacha has to say" about the issue, not "can I have oral sex." My answer presents the different opinions in the Halakhic discussion on this issue, without issueing any kind of practical pesak. And so, as I've said before, I don't see what the problem is

Comment: If popular opinion is really strongly against this question, I think it should be remain closed, but **as a duplicate to http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/30440/759**, *not* because there's anything wrong with it.

Comment: Answers have been deleted per [our policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4474/759). If this question is ever reopened, please flag for a mod to undelete them.